# What is the best way for algorithm about insertion

Tags: algorithm, sorting, big-o

I have to choose the best choice of insertion algorithm

1.before inserting the data  ,we have to search the proper place 
by the binary search.After getting that place ,we insert it by kicking every right-hand index(after that wanted place) to the next 
right cell.Then, we can insert my data into that proper place.

2.putting the data into the last place of that array.And sort it by Merge Sort.

I have guessed that first choice takes time *O(logn)* (binary search), and *O(n)* search the proper place. Can I conclude that it all takes time totally *O(logn)+O(n)*?

and the second one is *O(nlogn)* (merge sort), and *O(1)* (put the data at the last place). Again, can I conclude that it all takes time totally *O(nlogn)+O(1)*?

---

If the given size of array is

a.) 30

b.) 2,000,000

which algorithms are suit to each size?

Comment: When adding big-O notation elements, you can simply throw away the smaller one. *O(logn)+O(n)* is the same as *O(n)*, *O(nlogn)+O(1)* is the same as *O(nlogn)*. Once *n* becomes large enough, the smaller terms simply become insignificant in comparison.

Answer (score 0):

if you have sorted list already, inserting new elements to list one by one makes more sense to me.
if you have an array. It makes sens to go another approach.